# How to validate array values within an If statement in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app, I am trying to display a button based on some values within the below array:

```
public filterList: Array<any> = [
    { 'name': 'Product', 'selected': true },
    { 'name': 'Client', 'selected': true },
    { 'name': 'Received', 'selected': false }
];
```

If `Product` is `selected`, and `Client` is `selected`, and `Received` is not `selected`
Then I want to display a button.

Else, I want to display an error message.

The below method performs this functionality, but it is not extensible. For example, if I update `filterList` with another item, it won't be checked in this method.

Instead of hard-coding the array positions, I want to loop through the array:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.checkSelectedFilters();
}

checkSelectedFilters() {
    if (this.filterList[0].selected === true
      && this.filterList[1].selected === true
      && this.filterList[2].selected === false) {
      console.log('Display button');
    } else {
      console.log('Display error message');
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can update this method so that it meets my above requirement?

*Note: when the app loads initially, all `selected` values are `false` & are updated by the user*

Comment: how / where are you running this function?

Comment: HI @bryan60 I have updated my question to show where I'm running the function. I've also updated the function so that it works based on the above array, but I run into trouble with this function when the array is updated.

Comment: @user9847788 : would you mind creating a demo on stackblitz.com so that we can modify it as per your question

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek can you try this link please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sykrzs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I haven't created a stackblitz before

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is converting the array to an object and checking that way tbh...

```
checkSelectedFilters() {
  const keyedFilters = this.filterList.reduce((acc, v) => Object.assign(a, {[a.name]: a.selected}), {});
  if (keyedFilters.Product && keyedFilters.Client && !keyedFilters.Received) {
    // button
  } else {
    //error
  }
}
```

this is assuming these names are unique in the array, but IDK how you'd handle that if they weren't anyway.

Comment: I'd definitely do something like this, when you talk about adding to the array it sounds like you want to add things in sets of 3s, which would need a different object model.

Use constants as well, that way if your string conditions change you can change them in one place.

Comment: Hi @iamaword when I talk about adding to the array I mean adding another object on it's own: `{ 'name': 'Something Else', 'selected': true }`.

Comment: In that case, assuming you would need specific business logic to deal with new combinations, it wouldn't much matter if you had a for loop or not. You could even use a nested object instead of an array if you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you want a function to map to an *ngIf.

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="isValidList()">Valid Button</button>
<div *ngIf="!isValidList()">Error</div>
```

And, taking sort of your logic but slightly changing it to be in my opinion slightly cleaner:

```
 isValidList() : boolean {
    let isValid = this.filterList.filter((f) => f.selected 
      || (f.name == this.filterList[0].name && f.select) 
      || ( f.name == this.filterList[1].name && f.select)).length == 2;

   return isValid;
 }
```

Additionally, using something named such as @bryan60 and his keyedFilters would be cleaner.

Assuming the logic for new items is that any new item must also not be selected, this would work without changes.

In the end though, your data doesn't describe the logic.  Adding a property for `shouldBeSelected` and comparing with that would be better still...

Comment: i'd say you don't actually want to use this in an `ngIf` in template as making a habit of that can be a performance drag. better to only run the function when the array changes (like if this is a form on model or value changes) and assign the result to a component property.